# Django Generic Views and Customizability

Tags: django

Referring to CreateView, UpdateView, & DeleteView, as I get further in to my testing, I am finding these - however convienient - to be to restrictive to customization.  I did a quick workthrough of using ModelForm last night (off of the Django docs), but wasn't successful.

Does anyone know of a good detailed guide for using ModelForm views and customizing forms with Django?

To elaborate why I am asking this, the many of guides I've found might refer to ModelView but are in fact using the aforementioned.  Also, because the many of guides I've found seem to be for much older versions of Django.

Comment: Have you checked the official documentation on [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/)? Also, [ccbv](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.10/) is a great tool to understand the generic views. Both are up to date with the latest Django release.

Comment: I have been through it, and tried duplicating it but couldn't get it to work.  I struggle with the django docs because they're not very explicit.  I'm sure if I was a top level developer I would understand everything they say, but I don't.  I need to see and understand the structure of how things work.

Comment: I will check out ccbv, thanks for the link!

Comment: I see, maybe you need a deeper and more detailed explanation on these topics. If you want to explain a little bit more of what you need I could reply here later with a more in-depth response.

Comment: Well, they don't really lay out the structure or path of how ModelForm works very well.  File structure, pathing, etc.  This, leads to that which leads to those which render as these, etc.  I would love to create custom forms with widgets like a datepicker, or expanded text box size, or a dropdown instead of a textbox.  They don't tell you what goes in to your urls.py, views.py, models.py, or template explicitely.  Admittedly though, it's not meant to be a tutorial.

Comment: Taking a quick look at this guide [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/) it seems that they cover plenty of the most common usage cases. Some things you mentioned are not so trivial for the "default" Django usage so I agree that it'd need a deeper look on how things work and requires more work that is not covered in the base docs. SO already has a lot of Q&As on those topics and some open source libraries also help on that. You can search and compare those on [django package](https://djangopackages.org/)